# Routing Middleware does not preserve headers

Tags: routes, cakephp, middleware

I try to handle CORS for the API scoped route. If i get an OPTION request i return the response immediately so the application does not have to handle it. But if i receive a GET request i add the correct headers and return the updated response to the controller (or other middleware if there is any) but then in the controller the response object ($this->response) does not have the previously set headers anymore.

```
$routes->plugin(
    'Ark',
    ['path' => '/ark'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes)
    {
        $routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);
        $routes->registerMiddleware('cors', function($req, $res, $next) {
            $lAllowed = [
                'localhost:8081',
                'localhost:8082',
                'localhost:8087',
                '172.16.1.225',
                '172.16.1.225:8081',
                '172.16.1.225:8082',
                '172.16.1.225:8087',
                '172.16.1.224',
            ];

            if( $sOrigin = $req->getHeader('origin') )
            {
                $sOrigin = reset($sOrigin);
                $sOrigin = str_replace('https://', '', $sOrigin);
                $sOrigin = str_replace('http://', '', $sOrigin);
            }
            if( empty($sOrigin) )
                $sOrigin = $req->host();

            /** @var \Cake\Http\ServerRequest $req */
            /** @var \Cake\Http\Response $res */
            if( in_array($sOrigin, $lAllowed) )
            {
                //debug( 'Allow' );

                $res = $res->cors($req)
                    ->allowOrigin($req->getHeader('origin')) //only one host should be allowed when allow credentials is true
                    ->allowMethods(['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
                    ->allowHeaders(['Content-Type', 'X-CSRF-Token', 'Authorization'])
                    ->allowCredentials()
                    ->maxAge(3600) //1h
                    ->build();


                //return immediately for CORS requests
                if ( strtoupper($req->getMethod()) === 'OPTIONS' )
                {
                    return $res->withStatus(200, 'You shall pass!!');
                }

                //debug( $res );
            }

            return $next($req, $res);
        });


        $routes->prefix('Api', ['path' => '/api'], function(RouteBuilder $route) {
            // Parse specified extensions from URLs
            $route->setExtensions(['json']);

            //allow external services use this api
            $route->applyMiddleware('cors');


            $route->prefix('V1', ['path' => '/v1'], function(RouteBuilder $route) {
                // Translates to `Controller\Api\V1\` namespace

                $lListOfResources = [
                    //Table names...
                ];
                foreach ($lListOfResources as $sResourceName)
                {
                    $route->resources($sResourceName, [
                        'map' => [
                            ':id/restore' => ['action' => 'restore', 'method' => ['PUT', 'PATCH']],
                            'list' => ['action' => 'list', 'method' => 'GET'],
                            'filter/*' => ['action' => 'filter', 'method' => 'GET'],
                        ]
                    ]);
                }

                $route->fallbacks();
            });
        });

        //default landing page
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages']);
    }
);
```

Is this a bug or can RoutingMiddleware not modify the response before any controller action?
Should i add the CORS logic inside the controllers beforeFilter?

cakephp 4.2.12
php 8.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to user ndm i could fix the problem by modifying the response AFTER the controller was executed

```
$routes->plugin(
    'Ark',
    ['path' => '/ark'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes)
    {
        $routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);
        $routes->registerMiddleware('cors', function($req, $res, $next) {
            $lAllowed = [
                'localhost:8081',
                'localhost:8082',
                'localhost:8087',
                '172.16.1.225',
                '172.16.1.225:8081',
                '172.16.1.225:8082',
                '172.16.1.225:8087',
                '172.16.1.224',
            ];

            if( $sOrigin = $req->getHeader('origin') )
            {
                $sOrigin = reset($sOrigin);
                $sOrigin = str_replace('https://', '', $sOrigin);
                $sOrigin = str_replace('http://', '', $sOrigin);
            }
            if( empty($sOrigin) )
                $sOrigin = $req->host();

            /** @var \Cake\Http\ServerRequest $req */
            /** @var \Cake\Http\Response $res */
            if( in_array($sOrigin, $lAllowed) )
            {
//                debug( 'Allow' );

                //return immediately for CORS requests
                if ( strtoupper($req->getMethod()) === 'OPTIONS' )
                {
                    $res = $res->cors($req)
                        ->allowOrigin($req->getHeader('origin')) //only one host should be allowed when allow credentials is true
                        ->allowMethods(['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
                        ->allowHeaders(['Content-Type', 'X-CSRF-Token', 'Authorization'])
                        ->allowCredentials()
                        ->maxAge(3600) //1h
                        ->build();

                    return $res->withStatus(200, 'You shall pass!!');
                }


                //run other middleware or controller action, which will generate the final response
                $res = $next($req, $res);

                //apply CORS headers
                return $res->cors($req)
                    ->allowOrigin($req->getHeader('origin')) //only one host should be allowed when allow credentials is true
                    ->allowMethods(['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
                    ->allowHeaders(['Content-Type', 'X-CSRF-Token', 'Authorization'])
                    ->allowCredentials()
                    ->maxAge(3600) //1h
                    ->build();
            }

            //run default handling, no CORS applied
            return $next($req, $res);
        });


        $routes->prefix('Api', ['path' => '/api'], function(RouteBuilder $route) {
            // Parse specified extensions from URLs
            $route->setExtensions(['json']);

            //allow external services use this api
            $route->applyMiddleware('cors');


            $route->prefix('V1', ['path' => '/v1'], function(RouteBuilder $route) {
                // Translates to `Controller\Api\V1\` namespace

                $lListOfResources = [
                    /* TABLES*/
                ];
                foreach ($lListOfResources as $sResourceName)
                {
                    $route->resources($sResourceName, [
                        'map' => [
                            ':id/restore' => ['action' => 'restore', 'method' => ['PUT', 'PATCH']],
                            'list' => ['action' => 'list', 'method' => 'GET'],
                            'filter/*' => ['action' => 'filter', 'method' => 'GET'],
                        ]
                    ]);
                }

                $route->fallbacks();
            });
        });

        //default landing page
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages']);

        $routes->fallbacks();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior as of CakePHP 4.0. The response object passed to the middleware as an argument will not be passed to the controller anymore as it was in 3.x, that middleware syntax only exists for partial backwards compatibility reasons.

In 4.x, controllers will by default use a new response object, and middlewares receive it from the `$next()` call, respectively the `$handler->handle()` call in newer CakePHP versions, where no response argument exists anymore.

Basically, middlewares are not meant to be able to modify response objects that controllers could theoretically receive, they are meant to either return custom response objects to bail out early, or to possibly modify the response object received from the handler, which could be either the response returned from the controller layer, or one returned from another middleware.

If you want to pass any kind of data into the controller layer from a middleware, then you should pass it in the request object instead.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Migration Guides > 4.0 Migration Guide > Http](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-migration-guide.html#id8)**
- **[Cookbook > Migration Guides > 4.3 Migration Guide > Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-3-migration-guide.html#middleware)**
- **[Cookbook > Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#middleware)**

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, i could fix the problem

"possibly modify the response object received from the handler, which could be either the response returned from the controller layer, or one returned from another middleware."

`
//run other middleware or controller action, which will generate the final response
$res = $next($req, $res);
//THEN apply CORS headers
return $res->cors($req)
->allowOrigin($req->getHeader('origin'))
->allowMethods(['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
->allowHeaders(['Content-Type', 'X-CSRF-Token', 'Authorization'])
->allowCredentials()
->maxAge(3600)
->build();`